# How to wait until Firebase state changes?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I have a Firebase real-time database that has a list of online users.

Within my iOS app, I have a feature that loads up a queue of the online users from the DB.

When there are 0 users online, what I want to have happen is for the app to wait until the Firebase state changes and a user goes online, and then return the user's id (user.id).

The structure for my DB is very simple:

```
{
  "online" : {
    "user1" : val1,
    "user2" : val2,
    "user3" : val3
    }
}
```

Function I am trying to implement:

```
let rtdbRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "online")
userQueue: [String] = [] 

func nextUserInQueue() -> String {
    
    // once we exhaust our queue, load up more users
    if (self.userQueue.count == 0) {
        // need to wait until a user goes online, then put them in the queue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f) I wrote a few years ago, you can wait for a node to have a value with:

```
var handle: UInt!
handle = rtdbRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print("The value is now \(snapshot.value)")
        ref.removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
    }
})
```